# what does synchronization mean?

Tags: java, synchronization

would you please explain more about the meaning of synchronization?

Comment: i am sure there are lot of links that explains more about synchronization. Can you please be specific what your not able to understand in synchronization.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Synchronization is the way two or more threads can safely access shared resources without overwriting each other's work.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: Also, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)

Comment: Sun's tutorial is quite good. However, note that in the tutorial, "Synchronization" is one of the chapters in the "Concurrency" lesson. I suggest starting from the beginning of the lesson: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: The other option is using java.util.concurrent Atomic primitives, which can be used to implement STM, which lowers the cost of synchronization.

Comment: Can multiple threads run synchronized methods concurrently in the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Synchronization if work in multi threaded environment. Local variables inside methods are thread safe. If you are using global variables (including class level variables) you need to synchronize the method.